# How to resolve conflict in maven dependencies apache: commons-fileupload 1.3.2 and commons-io 2.5

Tags: maven, jhipster

I have developed an app using jhipster generator. I have only slightly changed the pom.xml file. I needed the commons file-upload to be able to receive multipart requests. I am not sure but i believe that was the only change i have made.

I have only noticed the maven build problems when started trying to build the production image.

My IntelliJ uses bundled maven 2 and it works fine there, but when I switch back to maven 3 bundled or installed in my operating system (windows  7 x64) I receive this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:39)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:122)
        at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main(MavenWrapperMain.java:50)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/maven/exception/ExceptionHandler
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.getEnhancedMainMethod(Launcher.java:172)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:268)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.maven.exception.ExceptionHandler
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
        ... 17 more
```

I believe one of the reasons my be conflict in my dependencies.

Here is snapshot of intelij analysis of my pom.xml.

[image: snapshot of intelij analysis of my pom.xml page 1]
[image: snapshot of intelij analysis of my pom.xml page 2]

**[edit 1]**

I have gave up trying to resolve this error. So what i tried to do now is to generate a new project with jhipster and copy all custom elements that was created by me into it. 
And here i stumbled on a problem, which is i can`t really do that, uperantly i have upgraded the jhipster-generator package incorrectly somewhere in the past. 
So now  on freshly generated projects i receive the same error + in my webapp bunch of files has an error like "ng-jhipster has no exported class AlertService" or the same but instead of AlertService it`s EventManager or some other class but it`s always the same package. Yes tried upgrading it.
I have found similar classes with Jhi prefixes on them in @ngx-jhipster package so it seams to me as as generator uses classes for one version of jhipster and package.json, pom.xml for another.

I tried upgrading the jhipster-generator, yarn and yo, removing the jhipster-generator dependency altogether and adding them back again, and generating projects again. Nothing worked =(

Comment: Have you tried running `mvnw`? mvn wrapper configured in your project by JHipster. How did you declare the dependency you added to your pom.xml, did you set its version?

Comment: yea i tried, got the same error. Sorry i don`t know what a wrapper is, Hold on a sec i will google it.

Comment: Please post the git diff of your pom.xml between your current version and initial version after JHipster generation. I suppose of course that you have committed your project immediately after generation

Comment: well i can see the mvnw file in the root of my project. It  was generated by jhipster and I have not change it so i presume it is configured.

Comment: Oh sorry you meant only the pom.xml, give me a sec

Comment: Try removing  `<version>1.3.2</version>` as I'm pretty sure spring boot takes care of it already.

Comment: sorry that was an older commit, i forgot to push all the changes i have made. I rarely really use git

Comment: Hold on a sec i will try

Comment: Nope same exception